# Adding weka instances after classification but before evaluation?

Tags: weka

Suppose `X` is a raw, labeled (ie, with training labels) data set, and `Process(X)` returns a set of `Y` instances
that have been encoded with attributes and converted into a weka-friendly file like Y.arff.

Also suppose `Process()` has some 'leakage':
some instances `Leak = X-Y` can't be encoded consistently, and need
to get a default classification `FOO`.  The training labels are also known for the Leak set.

My question is how I can best introduce instances from Leak into the
weka evaluation stream AFTER some classifier has been applied to the
subset `Y`, folding the `Leak` instances in with their default
classification label, before performing evaulation across the full set `X`?  In code:

```
DataSource LeakSrc = new DataSource("leak.arff");
Instances Leak = LeakSrc.getDataSet();  
DataSource Ysrc = new DataSource("Y.arff");
Instances Y = Ysrc.getDataSet();  
classfr.buildClassifer(Y)
// YunionLeak = ??
eval.crossValidateModel(classfr, YunionLeak);
```

Maybe this is a specific example of folding together results
from multiple classifiers?

Comment: I think you should consult the Evaluating section of the following link: https://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code It states that you should not train the classifier before using cross validation as it takes care of training the classifier.

Comment: thanks again @Campino.  so i guess i shouldn't do the `classfr.buildClassifer(Y)` call before `eval.crossValidateModel()`.
but this still doesn't help me understand how to mix `Leak`-classified
instances with classified ones? poking at the Evaluation.java source...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the bounty is closing, but Mark Hall, in another forum (
http://list.waikato.ac.nz/pipermail/wekalist/2015-November/065348.html)  deserves what will have to count as the current answer:

You’ll need to implement building the classifier for the cross-validation
in your code. You can still use an evaluation object to compute stats for
your modified test folds though, because the stats it computes are all
additive. Instances.trainCV() and Instances.testCV() can be used to create
the folds:

http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/core/Instances.html#trainCV(int,%20int,%20java.util.Random)

You can then call buildClassifier() to process each training fold, modify
the test fold to your hearts content, and then iterate over the instances
in the test fold while making use of either Evaluation.evaluateModelOnce()
or Evaluation.evaluateModelOnceAndRecordPrediction(). The later version is
useful if you need the area under the curve summary metrics (as these
require predictions to be retained).

http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.html#evaluateModelOnce(weka.classifiers.Classifier,%20weka.core.Instance)

http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.html#evaluateModelOnceAndRecordPrediction(weka.classifiers.Classifier,%20weka.core.Instance)

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your classifier, it could be very easy! Weka has an interface called `UpdateableClassifier`, any class using this can be updated after it has been built! The following classes implement this interface:

- HoeffdingTree
- IBk
- KStar
- LWL
- MultiClassClassifierUpdateable
- NaiveBayesMultinomialText
- NaiveBayesMultinomialUpdateable
- NaiveBayesUpdateable
- SGD
- SGDText

It can then be updated something like the following:

```
 ArffLoader loader = new ArffLoader();
 loader.setFile(new File("/data/data.arff"));
 Instances structure = loader.getStructure();
 structure.setClassIndex(structure.numAttributes() - 1);

 NaiveBayesUpdateable nb = new NaiveBayesUpdateable();
 nb.buildClassifier(structure);
 Instance current;
 while ((current = loader.getNextInstance(structure)) != null) {
   nb.updateClassifier(current);
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply @campino.  but unless I'm missing something, this is simply an incremental-add interface for these classifiers, adding new UNCLASSIFIED instances?  I seek a way to inject CLASSIFIED instances just so they are included in the same EVALUATION?

Comment: It is an interface to incremental classification models that can learn using one instance at a time. But the `updateClassifier` method updates a classifier using the given instance.

Comment: but i don't want the classifier to do its classification job:  i want the otherwise-classified instance to simply be part of the evaluated set of instances.